# Swift - Scheduled Timer does not fire as expected

Tags: ios, swift, timer, event-handling

I defined and fired a scheduled timer with a time interval of 0.1 second (which means 10 times per second), and set the selector to be a function that calls the completion handler of a VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest.

This works as expected on an iPhone 6s and an iPhone 7. However when I tested on an iPad mini 2, the request will only be called 1 time per second.

Is it because that iPad mini 2 is too old and does not have enough system resource to call it that frequently or something other reasons?

Below is the relevant code:

```
var handler: VNImageRequestHandler?
var request: VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest?    

faceTrackingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.callHandler), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)   
faceTrackingTimer.fire()

// This is called about 30 times per second (frame capturing rate)
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
    handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: .right, options: [:])
    request = VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest { (request, error) in
    guard let results = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation] else { return }
        // process results here
    }
}

// Problem: this is called ONLY ONCE PER SECOND    
@objc func callHandler() {
    print("Will call handler ", Date()) 
    do {
    guard let handler = handler, let request = request else { return }
        try handler.perform([request])
    } catch let requestError {
        print(requestError.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try timing the `captureOutput` function on the iPad mini and see how long each execution of the function takes. Without doing some actual physical testing it's quite hard to tell if the processing power is the bottleneck as you suspect or not. You can use Instruments in Xcode for low overhead timing analysis.

Comment: a)if you use scheduledTimer, don't need to use fire() again. Otherwise, use init() and then fire() seems more naturally. b)Vision framework is quite new. Don't use it at old slow devices.